# How to get correct URL to offer or correct price of offer in Amazon Product API

Tags: api, product, amazon-product-api

Try to work with Amazon Product API. Lot of code work, but have a problem, when get a lowest price, I get, for example, 0.01$. Ok, output near URL using response.item.DetailPageURL get URL not to offer with price 0.01$, but with other price (0.70$). So looking deeper I find out that offer with 0.01$ ask 5$ additional for shipping. And offer with price 0.70$ looks like lowest, cause it has free shipping. So, I wonder how can I obtain URL to offer with price 0.01$, so I output lowest price and URL to it, or how can I obtain price 0.70$ and left links as it is now? How to make URL and price from one offer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have dive into this problem and find out that there is no way to choose what offer will be send to me by amazon in response. The only way is show price from this path item.Offers.Offer.OfferListing.Price.FormattedPrice and gave the like to all offers on this item. So you will have price, for example, $0.01 and link to all offer where first will be the best by total price including shipping, but item price in top of page will be as you describe on you side $0.01.